# Архивация файлов, находящихся в MemoryStream

Tags: c#, sql-server, архивация

На сервере в БД хранятся файлы. Необходимо отправлять эти файлы на почту.
Я считываю файлы из БД в MemoryStream. Получается, что я имею несколько MemoryStream потоков, каждый из которых является файлом. Мне необходимо заархивировать эти файлы (потоки), что бы потом отправить этот архив вместе с сообщением на почту. Как правильно упаковывать данные файлы(потоки) в архив и указывать правильное расширение этих файлов в архиве, что бы получатель мог разархивировать и открыть данные файлы?

**UPD 0.** Я могу перевести MemoryStream'ы в массивы байтов, может их можно как то правильно заархивировать?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под словом `архивация`?

Comment: @ヒミコ создание архива, в котором будут содержаться файлы в максимально сжатом виде (картинки, документы, бинарные файлы)

Comment: _на стороне клиента сохраняю_ - так у вас есть клиент - некая программа? Или вы всё же на почту (email) файлы шлёте?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov согласен, не совсем понятный пример был. Перефразировал вопрос полностью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функционалом класса [ZipArchive](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive).

Пусть, например, есть два потока

```cs
Stream stream1 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello"));
Stream stream2 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("World"));
```

Положить их в архив можно так

```cs
using (var fileStream = File.Create("Archive.zip"))
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("Hello.txt");
    using (var zeStream = zipEntry.Open())
        stream1.CopyTo(zeStream);

    var zipEntry2 = zipArchive.CreateEntry("World.txt");
    using (var zeStream = zipEntry2.Open())
        stream2.CopyTo(zeStream);
}
```

В вашем случае, соответственно, будет цикл по потокам.

Если файлы объёмные, то вместо использования *MemoryStream* целесообразнее может быть протянуть поток напрямую из БД.

Это можно сделать с помощью [SqlDataReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader). Что-то наподобие

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = /* команда для получения данных из БД */;
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        int dataFieldIndex = ...;
        using (var dataStream = reader.GetStream(dataFieldIndex))
        {
            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("FileName.ext");
            using (var zeStream = zipEntry.Open())
                dataStream.CopyTo(zeStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание на модификатор *CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess* у метода *ExecuteReader*. При его использовании метод *GetStream* возвращает [SqlSequentialStream](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlSequentialStream.cs.html) (внутренний класс в *System.Data.SqlClient*), который вычитывает данные пакетами по мере необходимости. Если не использовать *SequentialAccess*, то метод *GetStream* будет вычитывать данные **полностью** и возвращать их обёрнутыми в *MemoryStream*.

Если бинарные данные в БД лежат в столбце с типом `varbinary(max) FILESTREAM`, то, вдобавок, можно вытащить их с помощью [SqlFileStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream).